# Insert into select statement produces #1064 error

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does this SQL statement produce the error statement further below ?

```
INSERT INTO members ('','Prep','name@email.co.uk',password,salt) 
SELECT password, salt 
FROM member
where id=3
```

Error statement

```
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''','Prep','name@email.co.uk',password,salt) SELECT * FROM member where ...' at line 1
```

Comment: You don't have columns '','Prep','name@email.co.uk' or perhaps you do and they should be backticked..nb ('','Prep','name@email.co.uk',password,salt)  are all the columns to be inserted to...table definition and example would help..you appear to be cloning id 3

Comment: thanks @P.Salmon i have 4 columns in this table, ID (Autoincrement), name, email, password and salt.  I wanted to use the same password and salt as member with ID 3.  I will copy these details into the edited question also.

Comment: thank you @RiggsFolly it worked when I updated my statement with your suggestion to use column names and put all the VALUES in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this

```
INSERT INTO members (`name`, `email`,`password`,`salt`) 
SELECT 'Prep','name@email.co.uk', password, salt  FROM member where id=3
```

***BIG Note*** Dont salt your own password hash, use [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) it does a better job on its own than you are likely to do and then  [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Note that the functions mentioned here are PHP functions. The OP does not state he is using PHP.

Comment: @SebDieBln Thats a good point. Ignore the additional `BIG Note` is you are not using PHP

Answer (score -1):

Because when you use insert statement and select like this, MySql except you to provide a complete row to insert from the select.

To insert only one line but using a column from a select, you will likely use something like this :

```sql
INSERT INTO members ('',
                     'Prep',
                     'name@email.co.uk',
                      SELECT password FROM member where id=3
                      SELECT salt FROM member where id=3
)
```